# SQLite3 not actually inserting

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to make a database for a management bot, I'm using sqlite3 to store how many warns and mutes a user receives, I have a command called `viewpunishments` to show how many warns and mutes a user have received, now obviously sometimes a user will have no warns/mutes so I have to make sure the column is set to 0 and not NULL, but it is not setting to zero, instead it is staying null

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('levels.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT mute,warn FROM lvl WHERE dID=?", (guy.id,))
selection = c.fetchone()
print(selection)

if selection == None:
    c.execute("UPDATE lvl SET mute=0 WHERE dID=?", (guy.id,))
    conn.commit()
    print("zero'd out the mutes")
    c.execute("UPDATE lvl SET warn=0 WHERE dID=?", (guy.id,))
    conn.commit()
    print("zero'd out the warns")
    print("update if not found")
    c.execute("SELECT warn,mute FROM lvl WHERE dID=?", (guy.id,))
    peeps = c.fetchall()
    print(peeps)
```

Pretty much I am:

1. Setting up a connection
2. Querying to see if the user has any warns/mutes
3. If they don't have any (request comes back null or None)
4. Make sure it is 0 and not NULL
5. But it is always coming back null no matter what

What inserts into the DB, which is already created:

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO lvl VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)', (message.author.id, 1, 1, 0, 0))
```

it is set up like this,

1. ID
2. xp
3. level
4. mute
5. warn

Here is an example of the same concept that **WORKS**:

```
c.execute("SELECT warn FROM lvl WHERE dID=?", (guy.id,))
        print(c.fetchone())
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels,id=424686228395393025) 
        if c.fetchone() == None:
            c.execute("UPDATE lvl SET warn=0 WHERE dID=?", (guy.id,))
            conn.commit()
        print("updated warns if not exist")
        c.execute("UPDATE lvl SET warn=warn+1 WHERE dID=?",(guy.id,))
        conn.commit()
        print("add warn")
        c.execute("SELECT warn FROM lvl WHERE dID=?",(guy.id,))
        warnings = c.fetchone()
        print(warnings)
```

The above has worked flawlessly with no errors

Comment: The entire database works just fine, as other commands work with the database without errors, so that is not the issue

Comment: This is what the print statements printed out: `None
zero'd out the mutes
zero'd out the warns
update if not found
[]`

Comment: Why not just make the column an `INT NONNULL` instead of an `INT`, with a default value of 0 instead of NULL, so you don't need this in the first place? (If you have a zillion existing rows, you can update them all in one go: `UPDATE lvl SET mute=0 WHERE mute=NULL`, and likewise for `warn`, and then `ALTER TABLE` the columns.)

Comment: I do have a lot of existing rows, what would be the right way to go about this?

Comment: Meanwhile, can you give us a MCVE—code that creates a new db, creates the table, inserts a row for the guy with NULL values, then runs this code and fails in the way described? Because when I test this the obvious way, there is no problem, so obviously what I mistakenly thought was "obvious" isn't actually what you really have.

Comment: The right way to go about updating them? Exactly what I put in the previous comment.

Comment: If I run it as-is, `selection == None` is never true, because the row `[None, None]` is not equal to `None`. (As a side note, you should check `is None`, not `== None`.) So, I never see the output you're claiming to see. If I fix that, everything gets updated to 0s. [See this repl.it example](https://repl.it/repls/LopsidedFuchsiaInstances).

Comment: I have edited the answer, abernert, selection == None is actually true for me and it tries to make them zero

Comment: Also, trying to set all the mute and warn coloumns to 0 also does not work

Comment: If your table is really set up like that, with a column named `ID` and no column named `dID`, then your code will fail with `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: dID`.

Comment: Also, if you `INSERT` the rows with 0 values, you get 0 values, not NULL values. Please give us an example that can actually be reproduced, or your problem is impossible to debug.

Comment: Sorry for that, dID actually works it the correct one, I will edit my answer with another example of the same conecept that actually works

Comment: [Here's an updated repl.it example](https://repl.it/repls/LopsidedFuchsiaInstances), showing what happens for non-existent users, and what happens for users with NULL values in the warn and mute columns, demonstrating that the code you've posted here works except for the incorrect test.

Answer (score -1):

As written, this code won't change anything. Not because you got the `UPDATE`s wrong, but because you're testing this:

```
if selection == None:
```

But `selection` is a row, returned by `fetchone`—a list with two values in it. A list is never going to equal `None`.

---

If the user doesn't exist in the database at all, then you might get `None`. But in that case, there's nothing to `UPDATE` in the first place, so you can skip all of this code.

But I'm going to assume you're not looking up a non-existent user, and that your problem does actually exist.

---

So, the whole `if` part of your code never executes. You don't get the output you claim to get in the comments, you get this:

```
[None, None]
"update if not found"
[[None, None]]
```

What you probably wanted to do is test each of the *values* in the list.

And you probably want to test them separately—if `warn` is 42 but `mute` is NULL, you want to update `mute` to `0` but leave `warn` alone, right?

Also, you should test `is None`, not `== None`.

So:

```
if selection[0] is None:
    c.execute("UPDATE lvl SET mute=0 WHERE dID=?", (guy.id,))
    conn.commit()
    print("zero'd out the mutes")
if selection[1] is None:
    c.execute("UPDATE lvl SET warn=0 WHERE dID=?", (guy.id,))
    conn.commit()
    print("zero'd out the warns")
```

With this small change, your code now works:

```
[None, None]
zero'd out the mutes
zero'd out the warns
update if not found
[(0, 0)]
```

---

All that being said, there's probably a much better way to fix this.

One thing you can do is set the column type to `INT NONNULL`, and give it a default value of `0` instead of the default default of `NULL`. (I think Sqlite will ignore the `NONNULL` constraint, but it's still useful documentation of your intent; the 0 default is the real important part.) Then, any new rows you create will have `0` values instead of `NULL` values.

What about all your existing rows that already have `NULL` values? Let's just fix them in one go:

```
UPDATE lvl SET warns=0 WHERE warns=NULL
UPDATE lvl SET mutes=0 WHERE mutes=NULL
```

Now, all your existing rows have valid numbers, and any new rows you create will have valid numbers, so you don't need any of this code in the first place.

Comment: This does not work, because the query does not return `[None, None]` it returns `[]`

Comment: @shtabbbe In that case, you don't even _have_ a row for the `guy.id`. The guy isn't in the database. So he doesn't have `NULL` values. And there's nothing to `UPDATE`. The problem doesn't even exist in the first place.